# Move SharePoint Events to Google

Tags: sharepoint, google-calendar-api

I need to move SharePoint events to Google Calendar. So if an event is created on SharePoint, it’ll appear to our client on his Google Calendar. If you tried it before, could you please share with me your experience?

Answer (score 0):

There's no out of the box solution for this however [this](http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/04/sharepoint-to-google-calendar-synchronization/) will help you to solve this. I do suggest having a SharePoint specialist or developer work on this task.